# Is there a way for on-the-fly pre-processing (splitting) of elements with get_dummies()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have been struggling with this one for a little while and I cannot figure it out.

I have some data that I'm trying to prepare and in the course of that I have to turn some categorical part of the data to binaries, using dummies (I figured).

The issue is that some of the entries in my raw data can in fact "belong" to one or more categories for the specific dimension in question, I hope this is clear in the example below. I would like to be able to attribute an entry to multiple categories, or have some kind of work-around for dummies (or anything else for that matter) that allows for that.

What I have looks like this:

```
In [116]: df_sample
Out[116]: 
    A           B          C
0  A1   12.000000       CAT1
1  A2    0.029767       CAT2
2  A3   -2.321058       CAT3
3  A4  121.000000  CAT1,CAT2
4  A5    0.493182       CAT3
```

By using `pd.get_dummies()` I get this (makes sense):

```
In [117]: pd.get_dummies(df_sample.C)
Out[117]: 
   CAT1  CAT1,CAT2  CAT2  CAT3
0   1.0        0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0        0.0   1.0   0.0
2   0.0        0.0   0.0   1.0
3   0.0        1.0   0.0   0.0
4   0.0        0.0   0.0   1.0
```

but I would, in fact, like to find a way to get this:

```
>>> pd.get_dummies(df_sample.C) 
   CAT1  CAT2  CAT3
0   1.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0   1.0   0.0
2   0.0   0.0   1.0
3   1.0   1.0   0.0
4   0.0   0.0   1.0
```

With row three switched on on both `CAT1` and `CAT2`.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sep=','` in `get_dummies()`

```
In [379]: df_sample['C'].str.get_dummies(sep=',')
Out[379]:
   CAT1  CAT2  CAT3
0     1     0     0
1     0     1     0
2     0     0     1
3     1     1     0
4     0     0     1
```

Comment: Yes, this will certainly do the job just fine. I was looking at the `pd.get_dummies()` function and there is no `sep` option there, unlike the `Series.get_dummies()`. Thanks